# Beanstalk - Updating instance software using configuration files

Tags: configuration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want that in each deployment of a repository, a "`yum install`" command will be executed.
I tried to create a configuration file: `.ebextensions/general.config` with the following YAML content:

```
commands: 
  01-command: 
    command: "yum update"
```

When I try to upload the repository using aws.push, it fails and the error on Beanstalk console is:

> Responses from [i-ca399786] were received, but the commands failed.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

## Edit:

I found the exact error in the beanstalk log file: "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo". It means that I have to edit /etc/sudoers in order to comment "Defaults requiretty" before executing the update command, and comment it out afterwards. The question is how can I do that elegantly in the configuration file itself?